# show string with \r\n in textarea with jquery

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to show a string value with \n\r in a textarea.

I set this in jquery with Model

```
var content = "@Model.Content";
$("#ListContainer #@Html.IdFor(model => model.Content)").val(content);
```

I use '' , `` for `@Model.Content` but get error

i get error  `"" string literal contains an unescaped line break`

how can i show this?

[image]

Comment: Use backticks to make it s template literal `var content = \`@Model.Content\``;

Comment: thanks, i use this but dont ok

Comment: Please right-click on the page, click inspect, go to console and click the link to the part that gives error and screenshot the result (you can edit personal information before)

Comment: i edit my question :)

Comment: And now do the same for the actual source code se in "view-source" or using "inspect" so we can see the part of the script where you have the problem. My guess is it is not where you think it is

Comment: when i set a default text , `$("#ListContainer #@Html.IdFor(model => model.Content)").val('sss');` it is ok , or when i replace content  `\r\n` with '' it is ok. or set a value without break line it is ok'

Comment: Please update your question with details instead of pasting code in comments. Also show what does NOT work, instead of what DOES work